# JMeter - add Lock in a Distributed testing

Tags: jmeter, locking, distributed-testing

I use a [Critical Section Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) in my jmx and I want to use jmx in Distributed enviroment, but there is a warning that it can't be done:

> Critical Section Controller takes locks only within one JVM, so if using Distributed testing ensure your use case does not rely on all threads of all JVMs blocking.

How can I still block multi threads for accessing same block for when using master-salve execution?

Can I use blocking using file system with [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather go for [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) as in case of creating a lock file you will need to set up some form of shared folder via [CIFS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939973.aspx) or [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) and HTTP Simple Table server can be used to orchestrate all the remote engines from a single host (i.e. JMeter Master instance)

You can install HTTP Simple Table server using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter HTTP Simple Table Server]

---

Another, easier, option would be going for [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) in conjunction with [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function so the "critical" section would be executed by only one specified slave.